# understand file processing with While vs For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to read a large file using several methods. So my code is supposed to look for and count how many times the text "time_data" shows up in a file. The total count is actually 24. However using the code I havee, it only finds 4 counts of it using a while loop:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        if 'TIME_DATA' in memcap:
            time_data_count += 1
        if not memcap:
            break
    if time_data_count > 20:
        print("time_data complete")
    else:
        print("incomplete time_data data")
```

Why is time_data_count only returning a count of 4? It's supposed to search through all of memcap and look increment each time it finds "time_data". I don't have this issue when I use a for loop like so:

```
with open(filename, 'r', buffering=102400) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    for line in f:
        if 'TIME_DATA' in line:
            time_data_count += 1
    if time_data_count > 20:
        print("time_data complete")
    else:
        print("incomplete time_data data")
```

What am I missing? Yes the file does indeed have newlines

Comment: any reason you're reading the first 102400 bytes in `f.read(102400)`?

Comment: It's breaking a 5.7GB file into chunks. But yes, apparently its faster than using readlines(). The program doesn't have to store everything into memory acccording to tutorials I saw on here @TenaciousB

Comment: this will only increment once if there are multiples in each chunk and will miss items if  `'TIME_DATA'` is split between chunks. Maybe use `time_data_count += memcap.count('TIME_DATA')`

Comment: @TenaciousB using pycharm, it skipped multiples in the chunks. Pycharm is such a good debugger that it lets you view and even search whats inside a variable. When I looked at what was inside memcap, it had multiple "time_data" in there but it only counted it once. Its bizzare

Comment: use `time_data_count += memcap.count('TIME_DATA')` the way you are doing it is incrementing by 1 if there are any found, not for each one in the string

Comment: @TenaciousB can you explain just what that line is doing.? What is memcap.count?

Comment: `memcap` is the chunk you defined in the code,  `count('TIME_DATA')` returns an integer with the number of occurrences of the `'TIME_DATA'`. `count()` is a built-in string method

Comment: @TenaciousB So you logic worked but I noticed something when i stepped through the code. With the prior logic I had, I could actually see my file's text in memcap. Now memcap shows me weird numbers instead of text representation. It now takes a long time to step through the code but it somehow identifies the string through the numbers. To illustrate. Lines in my file now look like this: "NPT_IRST_2_NPT77 6305 6305 6497 6202 6202 6305 6202 6202 6392 6202 6392 6707 6202 6392 6102 6497 6202 6602 6305 6392 6392 6392 6392 6602 6202 6202 6392 6602 6305 6202 6497 6102 6001 6305 6392 6305"

Comment: see the answer below, `memcap` should not have changed from your original code

Comment: @TenaciousB It definitely changed, at least in the way pycharm steps trhough it. I just uncommeted my logic and memcap shows the string in my file again. But when I use your method, it goes back to those weird integers. Its crazy. Does using that count function make memcap a pointer or something. I simply don't know why it won't show me texts from my file anymore like it would without the count method. Keep in mind your logic works but its just mindboggling how it now shows numbers not strings in debug mode when you look at the values

Comment: @TenaciousB Thinking more about it now, there is a danger with using bytes. What if a line gets slipt in half because of the chunk size and that split just so happens to happen at "time_"... and the other chunk starts from "data'. This would lead to a miscount. How can I account for potential lines being broken in half?

Answer (score 0):

Use `time_data_count += memcap.count('TIME_DATA')` to count the occurrences of `'TIME_DATA_` in the `memcap` string. This will not count items if they get sliced in half between chunks of the file.

```py
with open(filename) as f:
    time_data_count = 0
    while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        if 'TIME_DATA' in memcap:
            # add the number of occurrences
            time_data_count += memcap.count('TIME_DATA')
        if not memcap:
            break
    if time_data_count > 20:
        print("time_data complete")
    else:
        print("incomplete time_data data")
```

The issue with your original code is the counter would only increment if the  item was found in the string regardless of how many occurrences, not for each occurrence.

Comment: Your logic works but I saw something when i stepped through the code. With the prior logic I had, I could actually see my file's text in memcap. Now memcap shows me weird numbers instead of text representation. It now takes a long time to step through the code but it somehow identifies the string through the numbers. To illustrate. Lines in my file now look like this: "NPT_IRST_2_NPT77 6305 6305 6497 6202 6202 6305 6202 6202 6392 6202 6392 6707 6202 6392 6102 6497 6202 6602 6305 6392 6392 6392 6392 6602 6202 6202 6392 6602 6305 6202 6497 6102 6001 6305 6392 6305" Why is this?

Comment: Thinking more about it now, there is a danger with using bytes. What if a line gets slipt in half because of the chunk size and that split just so happens to happen at "time_"... and the other chunk starts from "data'. This would lead to a miscount. How can I account for potential lines being broken in half? @Tenacious B

Comment: yeah I mentioned that in my answer too, I'd use `for line in f.readlines():` personally unless its one big line

Comment: So yeah that method would miscount due to a situation when it gets split at between lines. However, I have read that using "readlines()" is slower and dangerous for memory as the whole file is loaded into memory. I did time comparisons between the methods and did notice that the other methods that break the file into chunks do in deed finish the task faster. For example, your method runs the code 20 seconds faster than readlines(). So this leaves me in a bit of a bind @Tenacious B

Comment: I used readlins() and specified how many lines I wanted. Even though it appears it goes through the whole file, it doesn't find Time_Data. How come? @Tenacious B?

Comment: you need to read all the lines to get the total count, by specified lines do you mean columns? is your file multiple lines or just one super long line?

Comment: No i mean each line seperated by /n. The file is multiple lines. Its crazy how much faster your memcap.count() logic is than the other methods. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely related to your if not statement as that is the only thing that would break the while loop. Since it is while True, theoretically it would run forever unless broken. Since there is only one line that can break the while loop it must be within there. As you know, a while loop needs to have a break point, I would personally do it this way:

```
    byt= 0 #count the number of bytes (that is your 102400)
    while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        if 'TIME_DATA' in memcap:
            time_data_count += 1
            byt += 1 #iterate so that you count up to that value
        elif byt == 102400: #total number of bytes in the file
            break
```

This will run until every byte of the file has been read and then it will break the while loop. It's similar to what you were doing except slightly different, should work if you want to stick with the while loop.

Comment: Thinking more about it now, there is a danger with using bytes. What if a line gets slipt in half because of the chunk size and that split just so happens to happen at "time_"... and the other chunk starts from "data'. This would lead to a miscount. How can I account for potential lines being broken in half?  @eagleman21